# search for files on the server using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

for example, there is a server .1 and .2

on the server .1 I need to run a script that will find the files and compare these files with the files on the server.2, if the files are already on the server .2 then on the server .1 they need to be removed and I need to write all this in python

here is an example of checking files that I wrote and run on my computer, but it does not always work correctly

```
DIRECTORY_FILE = 'C:/test/1/'
DIRECTORY_FILE_SERVER = ['C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/', 'C:/test/50/TEST@LOG/sent/']

def preparation(find, direct1, direct2):
    file_smb = []
    file_alltime = []
    for i in find:
        x = glob.glob(pathname=i, root_dir=direct1)
        if x:
            file_smb.append(x)

    for dirs in direct2:
        for i in find:
            z = glob.glob(pathname=i, root_dir=dirs)
            if z:
                file_alltime.append(z)
                return file_alltime
    return file_smb, file_alltime


print(preparation(WHAT_FIND, DIRECTORY_FILE, DIRECTORY_FILE_SERVER))
```

I need to get 2 lists of files from this function (from the server .1 and .2) which I will continue to process and verify with another function

here is an example of how the files are in my test build

```
C:/test/1/TEST@LOG-2022-12-04.7z 
C:/test/1/TEST@LOG-2023-02-05.7z 
C:/test/1/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230329.zip 
C:/test/1/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230331.zip

C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@LOG-2022-12-04.7z 
C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@LOG-2023-02-05.7z
C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@LOG-2023-04-09.7z

C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230329.zip
C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230330.zip
C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230331.zip
C:/test/50/TEST@ONLINE/sent/TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230401.zip
```

now the conclusion is like this, but maybe there is a better solution? and I will also be very grateful if someone tells me how to connect and search for files on the server (example of searching on the server)

```
'192.168.0.2/var/log/TEST@LOG/sent/'
```

*current program output:

```
([['TEST@LOG-2022-12-04.7z', 'TEST@LOG-2023-02-05.7z'], ['TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230329.zip', 'TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230331.zip']], [['TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230329.zip', 'TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230330.zip', 'TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230331.zip', 'TEST@ONLINE_LOG-sent-20230401.zip'], ['TEST@LOG-2022-12-04.7z', 'TEST@LOG-2023-02-05.7z', 'TEST@LOG-2023-04-09.7z']])
```

Thank you so much for any help

Comment: How to connect to a server depends on what kind of server it is and what services it's running. For Unix-type servers, the answer is almost universally `ssh` and `scp`; for Windows it's whatever wretched "solution" Microsoft is pushing this quarter. Probably look for `psexec` for remote execution and Samba / SMB for remote file access.